# Python csv writer, numpy array to csv

Tags: csv, python-3.x, numpy

I have Python dict containing 4 key value pairs. Each value is a numpy arrays. Now I want to print the whole dict to a csv, forcing to write one numpy array per row.

```
with open(os.path.join("csv", title), 'w', newline='') as f:
  w = csv.DictWriter(f, list(data.keys()))
  w.writeheader()
  w.writerow(data)
```

Is what I have used yet. But some of my arrays get written to several rows instead of a single line.

Here an example of input data:

> {'DE': array([[ 38574.        ,  38538.1904,  39511.6190,  42521.1428,
>            50586.        ,  46282.5238,  42714.4761,  40612.0476],
>          [ 42798.4666,  42112.5333,  42277.8666,  42886.1333,
>            50224.3333,  48148.8       ,  44272.6666,  41210.2       ]])}

I expect the output so that, each line of my array is written on one line. Instead I get a file containing "\n" after a certain amount of digits. how can i force to write the whole array in one row?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of input data?

Comment: So what do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: sorry for that, i edited and hopefully this should answer the questions

Comment: your first example is not correct, Dictwriter writes each column based on the keys, the output should be in separate columns not one below the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DE` has a multidimensional array as its  value, `Inter` has an empty list as its value, you end up with two columns one with `Inter` as the header with an empty list in  its column and a second column `DE` with the `array` in its column which is exactly what the code should be doing.

If you want to alter each array length  try setting `numpy.set_printoptions`:

```
numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=1000)
```

Comment: Yes and no. I end up with the following file opened in excel: A1: DE, INTER, A2: 38574, 38538, 39511, 42521, A3: 48751, 54737, 58725, 60445, A4: 50586, 46282, 42714, 40612] and if i open it with the editor it shows me the "\n" after 4 values. and i don't know where they come from.

Comment: actually it is still not working as intended. Sometimes when i open the csv in excel everything is written to one cell and sometimes it is written as expected.